# Split array of objects into array for X and Y axis on a chart?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I've got the following json response from my database:

```
let data = [
{sum: "42", year: "2018", monthNum: "12", month: "Dec"},
{sum: "24", year: "2019", monthNum: "01", month: "Jan"},
{sum: "20", year: "2019", monthNum: "02", month: "Feb"},
{sum: "41", year: "2019", monthNum: "03", month: "Mar"}
]
```

And I wish to use this data for a chart where I plot the "sum" on a y-axis and the months on an x-axis. The issue is that I'm not sure how to make each x value correspond to the correct y-value. Whenever I try to plot it (by splitting the array and what not), the chart displays data wrongly, eg March will show sum 20 or January will show sum 42.

I tried something like

`data.map(m => m.sum);` for the y-axis and

`data.map(m => m.year + " " + m.month);`for the x-axis.

This just returns two array completed disconnected from each other, eg

`["42", "20", "24", "41"]`
 and

`["2018 Dec", "2019 Mar", "2019 Jan", "2019 Feb"]`

How would I "tie" these together?

Comment: What format do you want them to be eventually?

Comment: I did include year and monthNumber just so I can sort/filter them and display them in a chronological order. Ideally just something like "Dec 2018" on the X-axis is tied to the `sum` 42, followed by "Jan 2019" -> `24` etc

Comment: Well, the two are tied together by index. In other words, `sums[0]` and `dates[0]` are both for `data[0]`. Depending on the charting component used, that could be enough.

Comment: What is "tied"? In terms of JS in what format it should be, provide the **exact** example for this data

Comment: This is what my chart spits out: http://prntscr.com/mmv68j - which, you can see, are incorrect values for each corresponding month

Comment: Well, no need to separate the data before you plot, just handle the x/y axis as you loop through your single array and get their position at the time you want to display them (in the same way you are retrieving the axis points now)

Comment: Here's what the inputs for the chart requires:

      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          id: "basic-bar"
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: []
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "hours",
          data: []
        }
      ]

Comment: The returned result doesn't really make sense. Array is ordered. The `map` should tie them together. The problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Care to show me how to structure the data using the `data` variable I posted in the original post? Here's a screenshot of "what goes where". `sum` should go in the `series` `data` and months should go in `xaxis.categories` http://prntscr.com/mmv7tv